# Show that $T_{1,m} = S_{N}(f)$ when $S_{N}(f)$ is the composite Simpson's rule with N = ${2}^m$ and h = $\frac{b-a}{2^m}$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation-theory

Here is what I thought but two formulas can't match:

1.we know this formula below
[Richardson Extrapolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7soL.png)

2.we know these two formulas for composite Simpson's rule
[Composite Simpson's Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW4dk.jpg)

3.we know that $T_{0,m}$ is the value of the composite trapezoid rule approximation where the subintervals have length h, and $T_{0,m+1}$ is the value where the subintervals have length $\frac{h}{2}$

4.Therefore, plug in what we have in step3 into step2, then use step1 formula to calculate $T_{1,m}$
[see my calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl2Fg.jpg)

I figured out that there is still one term $$4\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}f(\frac{x_{j}+x_{j+1}}{2})$$missing in the parenthesis compared to the formula. Is there anything wrong with my process? Appreciate any help!!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: You should mention that $T_{1,m}$ are the values in the second column of the Romberg table for the trapezoid method. Moving from column to column is indeed achieved by Richardson extrapolation. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3485559/115115 for an example.

Comment: The biggest error at the start is to give the same name to two different sequences. You need to do the first sum with the subsequence $x_{2i}$, where $x_i$ is the sequence of the second sum. See my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3465005/finding-higher-order-method-using-richardson-extrapolation-with-integration/3465584#3465584. Another error is that you forgot the factor 4 in the Richardson formula.

Comment: Thank you sir!!!